# When does Taylor series for g agree with g

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

For $g(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ for x not equal to 0 and $g(0)=0$. How to show that the Taylor series for g about 0 agrees with g only at $x=0$?

I know that the maclaurin series for g(x) is $1-1/x^2+1/(2!x^4)-...$. Then we need to substitute $x$ with 0, but those $P_n (1/x^2)$ are undefined at $x=0$. So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong: this function is $\,\mathcal C^{\infty}$ on $\mathbf R$ and  all derivatives of this function at $0$ are equal to $0$, hence its Taylor series about $0$ is $0$. Of course, it doesn't converge to $g(x)$.

Comment: This question follows by "Show $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all n=0, 1, 2, 3... " And I proved that question using the method that the derivatives of $g^{(n)}(x)=P_n(1/x^2) g(x)$ and then I used induction to show that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Comment: So then I can just say that its Taylor series about 0 is 0 and it doesn't converge to $g(x)$? I am a little bit confused. When is its Taylor seires $1-1/x^2+...$?

Comment: The formula for the derivatives is valid for $x\ne 0$. If $x=0$, the limit of the $g^{(n)}(x)$ tend to $0$ when $x$ tends to $0$, hence a theorem on derivatives concludes $g^{(n)}(0)$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: $1-1/x^2+\dotsm$ is not a Taylor series, which requires positive powers of $x$. This function cannot approximated by a power series about $0$. This means it is not an analytic function.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can prove using induction that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $g^{(n)}(x)=Q_n(1/x)e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ for some polynomial $Q_n$. From this you can deduce that $g^{(n)}(0)=lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \ Q_n(y)e^{-y^2}=0$. Hence, the Taylor series of $g$ in $0$ is identically zeros, but $g(x)$ is only equal to $0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: I guess my question is why $g(x)$ is equal to 0 for x=0?

Comment: Oh it is in the question......Thanks!